# how to get last value shown yAxis highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm eager to find out if its possible to place last value in series to yAxis in highcharts.

It supposed to be simple label with last point value shown on the right side of the charts, dinamically chanhing when we add points to the chart.

thanks!

Comment: Sure this is possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably several methods.
One that I would use can be seen in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zXLZA/

```
data: [7,12,16,32,{y:64,dataLabels:{enabled:true}}]
```

This makes use of the datalabels, which are enabled only for the last data point.

The downside to this is that you need to specify that in your data.  Not hard to do, but may not fit your needs.

Another way would be to use a second y axis, and the tickPositions property:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zXLZA/4/

Comment: Im adding new points one by one to the chart dinamically - so if specify datalabels enabled for the new point - very soon all points will have those labels, but I need only the last one shown
How do I remove datalabels:enabled from all exept last?

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to use `tickPositioner` with second yAxis. In such case with dynamic data, everything will be computed itself, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3c4tU/

```
tickPositioner: function(min,max){
    var data = this.chart.yAxis[0].series[0].processedYData;
    //last point
    return [data[data.length-1]];
}
```

Comment: yep, jlbriggs offered the same solution
it still not good for single axis but works for me, thanks!

Comment: TickPositioner != TickPositions. And solution for one yAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/3c4tU/3/

Comment: Yes, tickPositioner may be a better option in that it keeps everything more dynamic and self contained.

Answer (score 2):

to get the highest value in any axis and series, use the function [getExtreme()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes%28%29). It will find you the extreme value (highest or lowest depending of the argument you put behind). Select the chart, the axis and the series before.

here's an example: (whith your chart associated to the variable 'yourChart')

```
var highestValue = yourChart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax;
```

It will return the highest value of the first Y-axis' associated series.

While this below will return the lowest of the second X-axis' associated series:

```
var lowestValue = yourChart.xAxis[1].getExtremes().dataMin;
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommended solution:

```
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                borderRadius: 5,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#AAA',
              y: -6,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.x == this.series.data[this.series.data.length-1].x) {
                        return this.series.name + ': '+this.y;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

we can make use of formatter for this

here is an example to display the last value
http://jsfiddle.net/kgNy4/1/

here is an example to display maximum value
http://jsfiddle.net/kgNy4/

In the example I have put

`dataLabels: {
    enabled: true
}`

so that formatter function will be executed

I hope this will be useful for you

Comment: but the position of such marker will be static - if I place it yAxis, it sholud be in the right place, but it wont

Comment: say in your first example - it supposed to be between 50 and 100 on the scale and if I add to the chart new point, the position of the label should change also. But how?

Comment: In such redraw the chart accordingly here is a working example for that http://jsfiddle.net/kgNy4/5/