# How to display tooltip only for last point?

Tags: highcharts

I am using live random data in my chart . Here i want to display current feed value in right side of chart which will travel along with chart's last point.

I am trying to display tootip in last point which series will added dynamically. But i am unable to add tootip to last point alone.

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Here is [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/a6pshutt/) and what i am trying is

[image]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064823/how-to-get-last-value-shown-yaxis-highcharts

Comment: Thank you very much for reply , can you please apply the same in following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/a6pshutt/). I tried it , but not able to get. Can you help me out..

Comment: @Ranjith Tooltip or dataLabel?

Comment: @Kacper Madej : I tried with tooltip but i don't have any objection to use some other options. I need to find a solution for this. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Ranjith Yes, I have added an answer.

Comment: Sure, you just have to add **datalabels: { enabled: true }** to your addSeries function. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/a6pshutt/8/

Comment: @jibriggs: Thank you very much. It helped lot.

Comment: @jibriggs : I have another question. I need a line which will travel along with datalabels. I have tried with plotline option here[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83kp2d4t/1/) . But line is not moving smoothly, it should move live marker(last point of chart). Can you please help to resolve this otherwise suggest me if there is some other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a tooltip you could use `toolip.refresh(point)`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a6pshutt/7/

```
              ...
              setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    y = Math.random();
                len = series.data.length;
                series.addPoint([x,y], false, true);
                series2.data[0].update([x,y]);

                tooltip.refresh(series2.data[0]); // <----------here

              }, 1000);
              ...
```

To show a dataLabel you could enable it for the scatter point in your scatter series.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/83kp2d4t/

```
        ...
        events: {
            load: function () {
            var tooltip = this.tooltip,
                series  = this.series[0],
                len     = series.data.length;
              this.addSeries({
                id: 'end point',
                type: 'scatter',
                marker: {
                    enabled:true,
                  symbol:'circle',
                  radius:4,
                  fillColor:'white',
                  lineColor: 'black',
                  lineWidth:2
                },

                dataLabels:{
                    enabled: true // <----------here
                },

                data: [[
                  series.data[len - 1].x,
                  series.data[len - 1].y
                ]]
              }); 
              ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for ur solutions. it helped me lot .

Comment: @ Kacper Madej : I have another question. I need a line which will travel along with datalabels. I have tried with plotline option here[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83kp2d4t/1/) . But line is not moving smoothly, it should move live marker(last point of chart). Can you please help to resolve this otherwise suggest me if there is some other options.

Comment: @Ranjith To [add a plotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine) and to [remove it](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine) you could use API functions. However, you would need to have some animation instead of doing destroy-recreate. It is possible to add a dummy axis with dummy series that will create the plotLine which could be updated and animated. Since you are already using a scatter series, then let's use that series - example: http://jsfiddle.net/83kp2d4t/2/

Comment: @ Kacper Madej : Thank you very much for ur reply and solution. it is very useful to me.